# Code compiles and runs but one part does not loop correctly

Tags: java, exception

here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class QuestionTwo 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

 String file;
  Float number;
  String File;
  double avgnumbers;

  DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.##");

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please enter a file name");

  file = keyboard.nextLine();

  FileReader freader = new FileReader(file);

  BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(freader);

  while(file != ("input.txt"))

  {
   System.out.println("File is not found, enter the filename again.");

    file = keyboard.nextLine();

  }

  System.out.println("The number to check: ");

  number = keyboard.nextFloat();

  String inp = inputFile.readLine();

  int count = 0;

  int sum = 0;

  while (inp != null)

 {
      int strnumber = Integer.parseInt(inp);

      if(strnumber > number)

      {
       sum += strnumber;

       count++;
      }

     inp = inputFile.readLine();
  }

  avgnumbers = (double)sum / count;

  System.out.println("The average of the numbers that are greater than " + number + " is " + avgnumbers);

  inputFile.close();
}
}
```

The problem that I am experiencing with this code is that when I write the wrong file name for the first question I get an exception. What I coded for was for it to tell me that that was wrong and that I should re-enter the file name so that it could do so. It then would theoretically do so infinitely until the proper filename (input.txt) was entered; I would like to note that the outcome of my code is to my liking and meets its requirements; just that it keeps showing this exception. It did this very thing with the other part of the code that asked for the filename, so maybe this relates to that. Though before I changed anything on a hunch I wanted to get some "peer-review"; any help would be heavily appreciated.

exception stack:

```
[DrJava Input Box]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dxfgb (The system cannot find the file 
specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at QuestionTwo.main(QuestionTwo.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
```

edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.jav
     a:267)

> 

Comment: where is the exception?  Please post the call stack.

Comment: To compare strings, use something like `file.equals("input.txt")`. If you use `==` or `!=`, it's comparing the object reference, which will always `false`

Comment: And please fix your format. Maybe reduce the code to the necessary bits. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (with emphasis on **Minimal**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an exception like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: abc123 (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at QuestionTwo.main(QuestionTwo.java:18)
```

on input of a non-existent filename because you are trying to create a `FileReader` on the inputted filename before checking to see whether that file exists.  The Javadoc for `FileReader(String)` specifies that a `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown "if the named file does not exist".

To fix this while still having code that reflects your apparent intent change the first `while` loop's condition from:

```
while(file != ("input.txt"))
```

to:

```
while (!(new File(file).exists()))
```

and move:

```
FileReader freader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(freader);
```

*after* the first `while` loop so that the `FileReader` is only created for existing filenames.